# Why $X \geq 0$ and $\Bbb E{X} < + \infty$ implies that $\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}y \Bbb{E}{(\frac{1}{X} | X > y)} = 0?$

Tags: probability, limits, inequality

Why $X \geq 0$ and $\Bbb E{X} < + \infty$ implies that $\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}y \Bbb{E}{(\frac{1}{X} | X > y)} = 0?$

I'm thinking about replacing $\Bbb{E}{(\frac{1}{X} | X > y)}$ with $\frac{1}{y}P(X > y)$ and applying Jensen's inequality, but it seems they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be the pdf of $X$, $F(x)$ its cdf. Of course, $lim_{x\to\infty} (F(x)) = 1$ and $ \frac{F(x)}{x^2} > 0, \; \forall x > 0$.

$\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{X}|X > y) \\
= \int_{y}^{\infty} f(x)\frac{1}{x}\, dx \\
= [(\int f(t)\,dt)(x) \frac{1}{x} ]{|_y^{\infty}} \, - \, \int_y^{\infty} (\int f(t)\,dt)(x)\,\frac{-1}{x^2}\, dx \\
= ( F(x)\cdot\frac{1}{x} ){|_y^{\infty}} \, + \, \int_y^{\infty} \frac{F(x)}{x^2}\, dx \\
= - \frac{1}{y} \, + \, \int_y^{\infty} \frac{F(x)}{x^2}\, dx \\
\leq - \frac{1}{y} \, + \, \int_y^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx \\
= - \frac{1}{y} + [ \frac{-1}{x} ]{|_y^{\infty}} \\
= 0$

Now take

$lim_{y\to0^+} (y\cdot\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{X}|X > y)) \\
\leq lim_{y\to0^+} (y \cdot 0) \\
= 0$

Comment: $X$ need not have a pdf.

Comment: @StefanHansen good point.